# Time ran out against bare king

Tags: rules

If player A, who has a bare king, plays against player B who has around 9 pieces left on the board, and player B timer runs out (let's say player A's timer has 3 seconds remaining), who wins the match? Theoretically speaking, player A has no way to win the game but by player B's timer running out.

Comment: It's a draw, due to no mating material.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a draw.  FIDE rule 6.9 states (emphasis mine):

> Except where one of Articles 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.2.1, 5.2.2, 5.2.3 applies, if a player does not complete the prescribed number of moves in the allotted time, the game is lost by that player. **However, the game is drawn if the position is such that the opponent cannot checkmate the player’s king by any possible series of legal moves.**

Since the player with the bare king cannot checkmate the opponent by any legal sequence of moves, the game is drawn if his opponent runs out of time.